# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException

Tags: .net, entity-framework, conexión

Buen día

estoy ejecutando mi programa en visual studio pero correr me arroja el siguiente mensaje, revise la cadena de conexión pero no le veo ningun error, por favor oyuda

The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development. This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que te esta diciendo basicamente es que no encuentra la cadena de conexion en tu web.config/app.config, esto puede ser porque el nombre difiere del que especificaste cuando creaste el modelo, o no se encuentra en la seccion de connectionStrings. Puedes checar si el nombre concuerda,  en tu DbContext debes de tener un constructor con el nombre de tu Etitities y que herede de : base("name=NombreTuCadenaConexion")

Comment: otra seria tambien que tu cadena de conexion no este bien hecha, te dejo un link sobre como configurar code first https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/